# Compiling mod_Wsgi with python 3.11 on Amazon linux 2: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

Tags: python, mod-wsgi, amazon-linux

Full output:

```
In file included from src/server/mod_wsgi.c:22:0:
src/server/wsgi_python.h:26:10: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
apxs:Error: Command failed with rc=65536

.
make: *** [src/server/mod_wsgi.la] Error 1
```

I've been trying to compile mod_wsgi with python 3.11 using `make` to no avail. I've already installed `python3-devel` but it doesn't look like `Python.h` is being installed in the correct location or something? I've even tried copying `Python.h` into the same directory as the code that is looking for it, i.e `src/server/`

I made sure to compile Python with `enable-shared` as well.

Where exactly is this file supposed to be located and how can I get it? I was hoping there was a `python311-devel` I could install but there is only up to `python34-devel`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with a pip install requiring thriftpy2.

A workaround that appears to be working for me is to expand the visibility of gcc environment variables as follows:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/local/include/python3.7m/
```